# querying from select statement

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Can we query from a query?

For example:

```
select * from (select budgetyear from bg_year)
```

Comment: Did you try it? What error did you get?

Comment: If you want your 'subquery' to be permanent, i advise you to make a View, so you can acces it without writting all the code again. And ofc you can query your subquery

Comment: i did like this `select * from (select budgetyear from bg_year) AS T1` and it works.Thanks guy!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the query you wrote won't work. The subquery (a.k.a derived table) must have an alias like this:

```
select * from (select budgetyear from bg_year) AS T1
```

The alias is required even if it is not used. It is an error to omit it. Of course in this specific example there is no purpose in having a subquery because the query is identical to this:

```
select budgetyear from bg_year
```

I assume that you have oversimplfied the question for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's called nested selects.
Have a look at this online tutorial:

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Should have a pretty decent idea of how to implement nested selects after completing the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Sure we can, every result set returned by a select is considered a table, therefore you can query that resultset (table)

```
select budgetyear from bg_year
```

this query will return a table, and you can always query a table.

Comment: Need to provide the Alias name like "AS T1" for result set..............as @Mark Byers mentioned.